# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG BINARY got BLOB

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace function CasLengthOfLongRaw( p_tname in varchar2,  
     p_cname in varchar2,  
     p_rowid in rowid ) return number  
AUTHID CURRENT_USER  as pragma autonomous_transaction;  
   l_length number;  
begin 
   execute immediate 
   'insert into TEMPCSSRPLLOB(LOBFIELD)  
   select to_lob(' || p_cname || ')  
   from ' || p_tname || '  
   where rowid = :x' using p_rowid;  
   select dbms_lob.getlength(LOBFIELD) into l_length  
   from TEMPCSSRPLLOB;  
   commit;  
    return  l_length;  
end;
```

For this Function I am getting

> error at Line 7 and ORA Error
>   ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG BINARY got BLOB
>   ORA-06512: at "CASLENGTHOFLONGRAW", line 7
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: A kind advice : Please don't add words like "ASAP", "urgent" etc. I removed it. In S.O, users  spend their time  to  help you  voluntarily.

Comment: Post description of TEMPCSSRPLLOB

Answer (score 0):

[The `to_lob()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_LOB.html) converts a `LONG` or `LONG RAW` value to a LOB.

From the error message your target column, `LOBFIELD`, is a `BLOB`, so it is expecting the source column identified by the variables `p_tname.p_cname` to be data type `LONG RAW`. Clearly, from the message, it is already a `BLOB`, so no conversion is needed:

```
...
   execute immediate 
   'insert into TEMPCSSRPLLOB(LOBFIELD)  
   select ' || p_cname || '  
   from ' || p_tname || '  
   where rowid = :x' using p_rowid;  
...
```

But as the function is called `CasLengthOfLongRaw` the problem really seems to be that the function does what you want but you are passing it the details of an unsuitable table and column  name for the operation it's suppsoed to perform.